# Call BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted event when timer stops

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that creates a timer. The timer makes repeated calls to a `DataTable`. I only want the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event to get called when the timer stops. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a loop in the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event handler and repeat the loop until the timer stops. More or less like so:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (s, _e) =>
    {
       // call the database
    };

    timer.Start();

    while (timer.Enabled)
    {
        // at some point: timer.Stop();
    } 

    // if we are here, timer is no longer Enabled
    // RunWorkerCompleted event will be fired next
};
```

(Obviously I ommitted setting the timer's `Interval` etc.)

Comment: How can you disable the timer if it's defined inside the event (so you don't have a reference to the timer from outside)?

Comment: @ZombieHunter the timer can disable itself within the `Elapsed` event handler, e.g. based on the data  (or the lack thereof) retrieved from the database call it made. But it's a valid point; of course the timer should be declared somewhere else if you need accessing it from outside. Also lambdas are not always the best choice. My code is just a snippet meant to give a picture of an idea.

Answer (score 1):

BackGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted is called after your DoWork event completed. So if you ensure the DoWork event completes your RunWorkerCompleted event should be called by the background worker.

Another solution is to create the timer outside your background worker and control the background worker instance from the timer. In the timer event, check if the IsBusy property is set to false and start the background worker or skip if IsBusy is true.

Sample:

```
_worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
{   
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Do your database stuff

    e.Result = databaseResult;
}

_timer.Elapsed += (source, e) =>
{
    if(!_worker.IsBusy)
    {
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```